# Usar Carousel Bootstrap 4 con otros Elementos

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estoy usando Carousel de Boostrap 4, pero la intención que tengo es que cada slide pueda ser un elemento diferente a una imagen o una imagen, es decir normalmente los slides usan o son imágenes pero yo necesito poder mostrar tanto imágenes como iframes por ejemplo.

Este es mi codigo.

```
<div id="carousel-data" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <div class="carousel-inner" id="carousel-inner"> 
      <div class="carousel-item active" id="carousel-item-1">
          <iframe src="http:url"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item active" id="carousel-item-2">
          <img src="imagenes/3CF205E7.PNG" class="w-100 d-block">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item active" id="carousel-item-3">
          <img src="imagenes/RH3072021.png" class="w-100 d-block">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Lo pinto con JavaScript ya que la información la obtengo de una base de datos, revise el HTML y se esta pintando de manera correcta, hasta ahí todo va bien pero el carousel no funciona es decir que no se cambia al siguiente elemento y al siguiente etc. por lo que estoy pensando que tal vez no se pueda usar diferentes elementos que no sean imágenes. ¿Podrían ayudarme? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si remueves la clase _active_ del segundo y tercer elemento, ¿sigue sin funcionar?

Comment: @padaleiana Muchas gracias era eso

Comment: En ese caso, por favor, ponlo como respuesta, y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando se cumpla el tiempo necesario para aceptarla.